# Keep value after postback updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox which is inside a updatepanel -> detailsview. When I click insert I basically call a method to update DB. Now I'm trying to save the value typed in the textbox in the textbox so I don't lose it.

Shortly I wanna set the textbox value, with the value that is inserted.

My aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="insert" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <Fields>
          <td class="style1">
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="500px" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                             DataKeyNames="strPositionId,nFolderId,tmVaRPosition" DataSourceID="ODSManualPosVaR"
                             OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting"
                             DefaultMode="Insert" SkinID="detailsviewSkin" EnableModelValidation="True">
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="strPositionName">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="strPositionName" Width="380px" MaxLength="49" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("strPositionName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="380px" Text='<%# Bind("strPositionName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </asp:DetailsView>
          </td>
        </Fields>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My Page_Load:

```
protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.Page_Load(sender, e);
    strSystemId = Request["nSystemId"];

    CheckPermission(strSystemId);

    if (!IsPostBack || !PageHeader1.SystemId.Equals(strSystemId))
    {
        RefreshGrid();
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When click insert:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDB();
    //Trying to store the textbox value in a session variable
    Session["Test"] = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("strPositionName")).Text;
    KeepValues();
}
```

KeepValues:

```
private void KeepValues()
{
    var txtName = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("strPositionName");
    var name = Session["Test"].ToString();
    txtName.Text = name;
}
```

When I debug it stops at KeepValues and the Session variable is working. But I still can't set the textbox.text to it.

Why does this not work? Is it because of a postback? All I want is the value inside strPositionName to be stored in a variable (working) and then set as textbox.text

Comment: why not move your `Session["Test"]` variable to the global.asax file and initialize it like this in the Session_Start method 
`HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = string.Empty;` also you could create a ClientSide JavaScript code and look at `__DoPostBack()` method also check the Mode of your Update Panel as well your code may need to be fired or triggered on the Init also look at creating a Trigger in the UpDatePanel as well ..many options

Comment: @DJKRAZE The Session variable works. The problem is that it won't set the textbox.text

Comment: try changing the code or populating the text in page_init

Comment: It has to be done on insert event